# Some pages in SharePoint not accessible with FQDN

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services, domain

My customer's network is designed to enforce business users to only access web applications with FQDN. Business users can only access SharePoint site with FQDN example: http://abc-intranet.abc.local

**abc-intranet** as the computer name and '**abc.local**' as full domain name.

The issue here is business users can access all pages of SharePoint and Project Server but they can't access SSRS Reports and one BI chart (created using REST/HTML5/JavaScript). SSRS is configured in SharePoint-Integrated mode. But when same business users access the SharePoint server remotely and open the SharePoint site in the browser then they face no issues accessing SSRS and the HTML report, all works perfect.

On SharePoint server, we can't access any SharePoint site using FQDN. Pages and everything can be accessed with only server name example, http://abc-intranet

From all business users laptop, they can ping both **abc-intranet** and **abc-intranet.abc.local**. I have never faced this type of issues before and stuck in between, cannot find a right direction to move ahead. Your any help is highly appreciated.